# Apache CXF - 2Way SSL server side - No Spring

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, cxf

I wrote a very simple web application running on Tomcat following this example:

https://www.javatips.net/blog/cxf-soap-without-spring?page=1

Is it possible to configure 2way SSL on server side without changing Tomcat configuration (server.xml) and without using Spring?
In other words is it possibile to change this code to check client certificates?

```
@Override
public void loadBus(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
 super.loadBus(servletConfig);
 Bus bus = getBus();
 BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
 Endpoint.publish("/ChangeStudent", new ChangeStudentDetailsImpl());
```

}

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Mutual SSL is negotiated when the client connects before any request.

So for apache tomcat, you need to change the *server. xml* to make the Connector to request the client certificate. No way around.

Mutual SSL has nothing to do with the Spring, you don't need that.

Just a note - there exists a protocol to "renegoriate" the SSL connection (e. g. to request client certificate for already established connection) , but I don't think you can do it in Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself :)
It is necessary to implement the doPost method of servlet, something like this:

```
 protected X509Certificate verifyClientCertificate(HttpServletRequest req) {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
            return certs[0];
        }
        // ....
        throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
    }


   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("DO POST");
    verifyClientCertificate(request);
    super.doPost(request, response);

   }
```

and use Tomcat server.xml configuration clientAuth="want"